# Couldn't determine an appropriate version of KRE to run. VS 2015 CTP 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a MVC 5 application using VS 2015 CTP 6, when i try to run web app using IIS Express it throws server error with Couldn't determine an appropriate version of KRE to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information which points to Asp.Net site unable to find the solution. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean MVC 6?  If so, which version of the KRE are you using? beta2 or beta3?  You should see it in your C:\Users\Username\.k\runtimes.  I believe CTP 6 installs beta3 of the KRE.  If it is beta3 you need to get the beta3 versions of your assemblies.  If you use * there is the possibility you could get a newer version like (beta4) and your project could stop working.

In Project.json example:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta3",
```

Also in 2015 CTP 6 it seems that it changes the nuget package sources to use the following:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I had to revert back to the old one which is the following:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

After I changed it back everything was downloading correctly.  Not sure if this is a bug or why it does this.  I asked it here [VS 2015 CTP 6 Nuget Package Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842138/vs-2015-ctp-6-nuget-package-source)

Answer (score 2):

It was enough for me to update the one dependency.
I changed **dependency in package.json**:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
```

to:

`"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",`

Finally I have **Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS (1.0.0-beta3)** package