# VS 2015 CTP 6 Nuget Package Source

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After installing VS 2015 CTP 6 it added the following url to Available Package Sources:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

and turned off the following:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

When it did this it stopped downloading all nuget packages.  I switched it back to the old one and everything is working again.

One thing I noticed is that the old feed is xml and the new one is json.

NOTE: I did upgrade the Nuget Package Manager after installing VS 2015 CTP 6.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Example Error:

> Error: FindPackagesById: System.Threading.Tasks   Response status code
>   does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of
>   range.).

Comment: Did you install this alongside an existing Visual Studio or on top of an earlier CTP? I don't know if it would make a difference, but I installed CTP 6 on a clean VM and updated nuget right afterward to 3.0.60225.100. I haven't had any issues, and I do have the v2 source (disabled) with the new v3 json feed listed. It's something of a long shot, but did you ever add a NuGet.config file anywhere in the project in question? I've noticed that if you put one inside the project, those sources don't show up in the Visual Studio list, but it does use that feed when building. Maybe there's a conflict?

Comment: I have seen other people that say it is working for them also, so I am guessing there is some conflict or setting somewhere.  I uninstalled VS CTP 5 before installing CTP 6 but there may still be some files conflicting.  I am not using a Nuget.config either.  We have about7 other machines that had this same behavior also.

Comment: yes I've the same issue and I try to fix it by modifying the default NuGet.config with notepad but that doesn't work

Comment: I did have a Nuget.config and tried modifying it and removing it, but it made no difference.

Comment: Looks like there is a known bug here.  http://blog.nuget.org/  Not sure why other people are saying it works unless they are not doing an ASP.NET 5 project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known bug.  It can be seen here:
http://blog.nuget.org/20150226/nuget-3.0-beta2.html